# CSS HTML JQuery code doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, sidebar

I have some code on my website for a popout menu that should appear and disappear on click of the button, I'm pretty bad at debugging HTML and JQuery, would someone out there be able to find why it won't pop in and out?

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

At the top

```
<script>
$('#trigger').click( function() {
    if ($('#popout').hasClass('hidden')) {
        $('#popout').removeClass('hidden');
        showPopout();
    }
    else {
        $('#popout').addClass('hidden');
        hidePopout();
    }
});
function showPopout() {
    $('#popout').animate({
        left: 200
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('#trigger span').html('Close');  //change the trigger text at end of animation
    });
}
function hidePopout() {
    $('#popout').animate({
        left: -200
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('#trigger span').html('Show');  //change the trigger text at end of animation
    });
}

</script>
```

In The Body

```
<div id="popout" style="float:left;width:200px;">
    <div id="nav-border-top">
        <div id="nav-border-bottom">
            <div class="container" style="width:200px;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">

                    <tr id="nav1">
                        <a href="BLANKED">Home<br></a>
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="nav2">
                        <a href="BLANKED">Forum<br></a>
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="nav3">
                        <a href="BLANKED">Blog<br></a>
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="nav3a">
                        <a href="BLANKED">> Photos Of BLANKED<br></a>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div><!-- end container -->
        </div><!-- end nav-border-bottom -->
    </div><!-- end nav-border-top -->
</div><!-- end nav-wrap -->
```

Also

```
<span id="trigger" style ="position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;color:#d3222d;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);width:50px;height:25px;">
    Menu
</span>
```

CSS

```
 #popout {
    position: fixed;                /* fix the popout to the left side of the screen */
    top: 50px;
    left: -200px;                    /* use a negative margin to pull the icon area of the popout off the edge of the page */
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    color: gray;
}
#trigger {                          /* create a clickable area that triggers the slide in/out effect */
    position: absolute;             /* position clickable area to consume entire right section of popout (add a border if you want to see for yourself) */  
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;   
}
```

Comment: Have you included **JQuery** in your project? Seems to be [working](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/TDjRY/).

Comment: My advice is not use table for the menu. Use ul and li for the menu. That's the best way.

Comment: Instead of this long script you can use something like this.

'http://jsfiddle.net/sajaycv/SUzJg/'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this long script you can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trigger').click( function() {

        $("#popout").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sajaycv/SUzJg/

Answer (score 0):

You said you included you scriopt at the top, but do not wrapper your event binding in a DOM ready.

That is the problem, you are adding event on non-existant elements.

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trigger').click( function() {
        if ($('#popout').hasClass('hidden')) showPopout();
        else hidePopout();
        $('#popout').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
function showPopout() {
    $('#popout').animate({
        left: 200
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('#trigger span').html('Close');  //change the trigger text at end of animation
    });
}
function hidePopout() {
    $('#popout').animate({
         left: -200
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('#trigger span').html('Show');  //change the trigger text at end of animation
    });
}
```

Comment: That script is good, but I have a feeling that the problem lies in the area with the span of id  "trigger" It won't change ion click, and it doesn't seem to toggle, see what I mean at http://wcsritchietheater.weebly.com/

Comment: In the console, I got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function ". Try changing all your `$` in this code by `jQuery`.

Comment: will do, however, I'm still not convinced that The Problem is the code, I think it's the <span id="trigger" style="blah"> tag
I don't think the thingy's clicking the code, and it's certainly not changing, the words on the span won't change with the clicking, look at the webpage and see what I mean"

Comment: Just saw something. `#trigger` is a span containing HTML, so : `$('#trigger span')` should be `$('span#trigger')`.

Comment: The problem is not there then : http://jsfiddle.net/hfQYR/. Any error in console?